# Edit specific div's using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

How can I edit specific div's using Angular? I have a upset of div's at my page, containing tablerows with data. When I click on a edit-button on a specific div, I want that to bed editable.

How can I bind the click event to that particular div? I have done something like this now:

```
<div ng-show="summary.abbData.service_type == 'NaoLan'" class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ffffff; width: 325px; margin-left: 15px;">
    <h5 class="bg-primary rmpad15" style="margin-top: 1px; padding: 5px;">{{summary.abbData.service_type}}<button type="button" ng-click="editAbb(customer.id)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="float: right; margin-top: -3px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></h5>
    <table class="table table-condensed pad1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Hastighet</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.service}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Läghenhetsnr</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.apartment}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Månadsavgift</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.month_fee}}kr</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Anslutningsavgift</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.conn_fee}}kr</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Bindningstid</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.fixation}}mån</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Registreringsdatum</strong></td><td>{{summary.abbData.reg_date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have ng-click, but I don't know how to bind the div to the click event. ANyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here [jsbin.com/zataro/2/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/zataro/2/edit?html,output)

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Läghenhetsnr</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-hide="edit.apartment">{{summary.abbData.apartment}}</span>
      <input ng-model="summary.abbData.apartment" type="text" ng-show="edit.apartment" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="edit.apartment=!edit.apartment">
        <span ng-show="!edit.apartment">Edit</span>
        <span ng-show="edit.apartment">Save</span> 
      </button>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you. But that don't make all the rows in a div editable?

Comment: @user500468 do you want to have  one button which change all divs to editable ?

Comment: No, I want a edit-button one every div. When I click on a edit button in a div, I want the table rows in that div to be editable.

Comment: @user500468 please see here http://jsbin.com/zataro/2/edit?html,output I've did first two rows for you you can carry on follow that pattern